# $var not working though out php mysql script

Tags: php, mysql

I don't understand why the second mysql look is not working. 
from what i can tell where `$sqlb = "SELECT * FROM emp_list  WHERE password = '$pw' AND username = '$un' LIMIT 1 ";` is on the second line there is no value in the $pw or $un in fact i can not echo any of the

```
$un = $_POST['username'];
$pw = $_POST['password'];
$store = $_POST['store'];   
$pw = md5($pw);
$ipaddress = $ipaddress;
```

from the start or $nip from the first loop What am i doing wrong?

```
     <?php     

    $ipaddress = '';
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']))
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
        else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']))
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']))
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
        else if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        else {
            $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';

 }     
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "******";
    $password = "**********";
    $dbname = "************";


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$connb = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname, true);


// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) 
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


$un = $_POST['username'];
$pw = $_POST['password'];
$store = $_POST['store'];   
$pw = md5($pw);
$ipaddress = $ipaddress;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM acclst  WHERE s = '$ipaddress' LIMIT 1 ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
   // There is an ipaddress and it is approved
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{

        echo 'welcome ';
        echo $nip = $row['s'];   


    if ($conn->connect_error) 
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}   

// this does not echo       
echo $store;

$sqlb = "SELECT * FROM emp_list  WHERE `username` = '$un' AND password = '$pw' LIMIT 1 ";
$resultb = $connb->query($sqlb);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   // There is an ipaddress and it is approved
    while($rowb = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
// none of this echo's

        echo $pw;
        echo 'welcome ';
        echo $rowb['namel'];        


         }
      } 
    }
} 


else 
{
    // There is no ip address and you do not have access.
    echo "0 results";
}

?>
```

Comment: you dont need two mysql connections, you should not be hashing passwords with md5. your running the same code block twice for no reason.

Comment: there is an unclosed ` at `username in your sql.

Comment: I did that because it was failing. I was trying to eliminate why my echo's were not working.  Why should i not use MD5? I have MD5 password in the password field of the DB

Comment: @imnoten Thank you but that didn't fix anything.

Comment: `print_r($_POST)`? Where's the `mysqli::error` checking? SQL escaping? Column name quoting (beware: reserved words)? Also don't store plain or md5 passwords; use passsword_hash/_verify etc.

Comment: Is this your whole code or just chunks that you felt were relevant? `md5` is insecure as is user data in a SQL query. Parameterize your query, `mysqli` allows you to do that. `SELECT * FROM emp_list  WHERE `password` = '$pw'  LIMIT 1` seems exceptionally insecure, just because someone matches the password doesn't mean they are the right user.

Comment: @chris85 code has been update with the correct version and there is no error. I have also commented where the echos are not working and the `echo $pw;
        echo 'welcome ';
        echo $rowb['namel'];        
` still dont print anything.

Comment: "Why should i not use MD5?" Because MD5 is **incredibly insecure** for password hashing. It is essentially no better than storing the password as plain text. PHP gives `password_hash` and `password_verify` functions for a reason.

Comment: So this no longer is an account login? Is the page's status a 500, do you get any output when you load this?

Comment: It echo's Welcome and $nip. But nothing past that.

Comment: what is `$dbhb` here?      `die("Connection failed: " . $dbhb->connect_error);`  pretty sure that should be `$conn->connect_error`

Comment: Why `if ($conn->connect_error) {` after using `$conn`, if you had an error it would have occurred earlier. You also should fix the indentation, is the `while` intended to be opened the whole time?

Comment: @ethorn10 Changed but mad no improvements to the problem

Comment: @KellyHansen you are missing the closing brace around that `if`. Or maybe not...I can't follow those randomly indented braces

Comment: @ethorn10 Good point i will remove it.

Comment: @ethorn10 Double checked they seem to all be there, sorry about the random indented braces i coped from DW and pasted and they did not line up right.

Comment: can you echo your `$sqlb`? i'm guessing your `num_rows` isn't `>0` so it doesn't get into that last `while` to echo. and your `$store` might be empty as well. move the `echo $store;` up to where you echo welcome

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i found. Now it works fine.

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $dbpassword, $dbname);


// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


$un = $_POST['username'];
$pw = $_POST['password'];
$store = $_POST['store'];   
//  $pw = password_hash('donavons', PASSWORD_DEFAULT);


$ipaddress = $ipaddress;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM acclst  WHERE s = '$ipaddress' LIMIT 1 ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   // There is an ipaddress and it is approved
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo '<pre>IP Address Verified.' .  $row['s'] . '</pre>';   


$sqlb = "SELECT * FROM emp_list WHERE username = '$un' LIMIT 1 ";
$result = $conn->query($sqlb);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   // There is an ipaddress and it is approved
    while($rowb = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

$hash = $rowb['password'];

if (password_verify($pw, $hash))
{
```

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if I understand your question, but try something like this:

```
$sqlb = "SELECT * FROM emp_list  WHERE password = " . $pw . " AND username = " . $un . " LIMIT 1 ";
```

Comment: no change. It does not erro our or anything the only thing it will show is echo 'welcome '; echo $nip = $row['s'];

Comment: @kkj You provided no explanation on why the stupid concatenation change and resulting SQL syntax error could have potentially helped.

Comment: Here is what im getting. Fatal error: Call to undefined function uery() in /home1/donavons/public_html/fuel_tickets/txt/log_user_in.php on line 170

Comment: What is your expected output? And what is your actual output?

Comment: log_user_in.php seems to be a different file, than the one you posted?

Comment: @kkj it should echo out welcome and the $rowb['namel'] which is there last name, its the same file as well.

Comment: Hmm... But there is no call to the function uery() in the file you've posted?

Comment: @kkj You are right im a compleat moreon! I coped the right code but wrong version :( Here is the correct one

Comment: @kkj I have updated with the correct version of the code. Sorry about that again!

Comment: Are you sure that is the code you are actually running? The error message you provided, indicate that there is a misspelled uery() some where in your code. But I don't see it in the provided file.